# Should we burninate [language-features]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

What does [language-features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-features) add?

To me it's a meta tag, as no one can be an expert on all languages. Currently there are 598 tagged.

Comment: Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow. Before burnination can proceed your question needs a bit more info on how the tag meets the burnination criteria. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with the burnination request. The tag is too ambiguous. What exactly language features does the tag exactly refer to? C# ones? C++ ones? C ones? As you mentioned, no one can be an expert in every language, so the tag can't help and therefore should be removed.

A question will need to have a language tag to understand about the language feature(s) it is about.